# "Bare" git repository: how can I let Apache always "see" the latest commit?

Tags: apache, git

We've got a "bare" git repository on a server, for a Web portal project. Several programmers, designers, etc... perform dozens of `push` and `pull` from/to it.

Now we want to test the project on the server itself, and always test the last commit through an Apache web server which is installed on the same machine the "bare" git repository is stored in.

How can we 'unbare' the repository, and let the working directory contain **always** and **only** the last commit deriving from the last `push`?

Or anything else aiming to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a post-receive hook to do a `git pull` inside your `webserver` document root/repository.

in your bare repository
do

```
mv hooks/post-receive.sample hooks/post-receive
chmod +x .git/hooks/post-receive
```

the post receive should be something like

```
#!/bin/sh
WEB_ROOT='/var/www/project'
cd $WEB_ROOT
git pull
```

A more elegant [solution](http://ryanflorence.com/deploying-websites-with-a-tiny-git-hook/) that doesn't involve that the web server area being a git repository, you can also review the git documentation about [hooks](http://fclose.com/p/linux/man/5-githooks/)

Note: if you use the simple solution, please make sure that your webserver doesn't serve the .git directory, **this would give some hackers/crackers the access to the website source code!**

Comment: Thanks for the security hint, but never mind since server is not on the Internet

Comment: @gd1: don't forget that most of the attacks also come the inside, i.e. some staff of your company. Better safe than sorry, forbidding access to the `.git` directory only take one line in the webserver configuration file.